# Microsoft Azure cloud service per instance address instead of port

Tags: azure, dns, cloud, scale

I am using Azure cloud service which should auto scale its instances count. Each instance is accessed through the same address using incrementing port number.
But now I need to use one port number(I'm using the most unblocked - 443), because many ports are blocked at public networks around the world.

The only solution I see now and that is my **QUESTION:**

Is it possible to automatically assign a next level domain name to each instance of my azure cloud service e.q. when my service address is myservice.cloudapp.net and each instance would have instance[i].myservice.cloudapp.net address?
Or maybe there is another way? I need to access specific service instance using the same port number.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ARR (Application Request Routing) to accomplish this.  If you search for 'Azure ARR' you will find lots of hits, but the post at http://coderead.wordpress.com/2011/10/13/using-iis-application-request-routing-to-load-balance-on-azure/ is probably a good starting point.